# Can "include" directive be used within upstream block of nginx?

Tags: include, nginx

My site uses two app server, namely app1 and app2, so in the configuration I have something like this:

```
upstream cluster {
    server app1:8080;
    server app2:8080;
}
```

Since every time I update the code I need to restart both server processes and I want the service undisturbed, I will follow these steps manually:

1. Comment `app1` within upstream block so to modify it into:

   ```
   upstream cluster {
       #server app1:8080;
       server app2:8080;
   }
   ```
2. Run `nginx -s reload`
3. Update code at `app1` and restart the server program, and then uncomment `app1` in upstream block
4. Do steps 1-3 for `app2`

I wish to write a script to spare this tedious work, so what I hope to do is this:

1. Have a folder named "available" which contains `app1.conf` and `app2.conf` in form as

   ```
   server app1:8080;
   ```
2. Have another folder named "enabled" to contain the soft links of `app1.conf` and `app2.conf`
3. Modify the upstream cluster into

   ```
   upstream cluster {
       include /usr/local/nginx/conf/enabled/*;
   }
   ```

   So every time I need to disable any app server I can just remove the corresponding soft link from the "enabled" folder, and later can restore it by running `ln -s`

However this approach didn't work well as I got an error message from nginx saying:

> [emerg]: "include" directive is not allowed here in ....

Is that so `include` cannot not be put into the upstream block? and I'd imagine I'm not alone in this kind of scenario, disabling and enabling server at times, how other folks normally  deal with it?

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, nginx can't handle include directive inside upstream,. 
But you can use this script to manage your upstream servers:

somewhere in http section of nginx.conf:

```
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/upstream.conf
```

create empty file:

```
touch /usr/local/nginx/conf/upstream.conf
```

use this script to manage upstream servers(**upstreamctl.sh**):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n "$1" -a -n "$2" ]; then
    action="$1";
    target="$2";
else
    echo "Usage: $0 (add|rm) server:port"
    exit 0;
fi;
# Path to nginx binary
BIN="/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx"
# Path to upstream config file
CONF="/usr/local/nginx/conf/upstream.conf"

SERVERS=`cat $CONF | grep server`

output="upstream cluster {"


if [ $action == "add" ]; then
    echo -e "$output" > $CONF
    if $( echo $SERVERS | grep --quiet $target ); then
        echo "Warning: Server is already enabled."
    else 
        SERVERS="$SERVERS\n\tserver $target;"
    fi
    echo -e "$SERVERS" >> $CONF
    echo "}" >> $CONF

elif [ $action == "rm" ]; then 
    sed -i "/$target/d" $CONF
else 
    echo "Unknown action"
fi

# Check changes:
$BIN -t
```

In your case you may run:

```
./upstreamctl.sh add app1:8080
```

and

```
./upstreamctl.sh rm app2:8080
```

Answer (score 6):

Just putting this here in case we can help others:

**Include directive can be used in upstream block in later versions of nginx.**

Example:

/etc/nginx/upstream.conf

```
server ip:port;
server ip:port;
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
upstream cluster {
    include /etc/nginx/upstream.conf;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://cluster;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you happen to know which version ?

Comment: I was using latest at the time, but you can easily test it by modifying the config and run nginx -t to verify.

Comment: It fails on 1.19.0 as `nginx: [emerg] directive "server" has no opening "{"  in /etc/nginx/upstream.conf:1`

Comment: @JackTheKnife, this error is happening mostly due to the fact that we are loading the configuration from http block. for eg: if we have a include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* and included "server ip:port" in a configuration file inside the sites-enabled/app.conf, then we'll see this error. otherwise, it doesn't error out. Tested in 1.20.2.