# add file contents between placeholders in different file

Tags: bash, sed

I need to add the contents of a text file between certain placeholders in another text file.
(Specifically, I'm trying to get around the nginx [include limitation inside upstream blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165116/can-include-directive-be-used-within-upstream-block-of-nginx).)

My main nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` looks like this:

```
## START UPSTREAM

## END UPSTREAM

http {
...
}
```

My server upstream file `/etc/nginx/upstream.conf` looks like this:

```
upstream wordpress {
  server    10.0.0.1;
  server    10.0.0.2;
  ...
}
```

---

I want to copy the contents of `/etc/nginx/upstream.conf` in between the `## START UPSTREAM` and `## END UPSTREAM` blocks. The desired result:

```
## START UPSTREAM
upstream wordpress {
  server    10.0.0.1;
  server    10.0.0.2;
  ...
}
## END UPSTREAM

http {
...
}
```

---

So far, I've tried to use `sed` (with the help of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715373/sed-insert-file-content-after-specific-pattern-match) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512362/how-can-i-can-insert-the-contents-of-a-file-into-another-file-right-before-a-spe) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243102/using-sed-to-insert-file-content)):

```
sed -i '/## START UPSTREAM/,/## END UPSTREAM/ r /etc/nginx/upstream.conf' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

However, the above code doesn't work--it just fails silently. How can I modify sed to properly replace all text between the placeholders?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '/## START UPSTREAM/,/## END UPSTREAM/{//!d;/## START UPSTREAM/r /etc/nginx/upstream.conf' -e '}' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: I get an error: sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `-'

Comment: Ah, thanks, it's working now. However, every time I run the command it duplicates the block like this: http://pastebin.com/Zvv8eb3e. How can I make sure it also replaces all of the current block contents?

Comment: I'm guessing here. But I think you may need to edit your `nginx.conf` file back into a pristine state then apply above solution. It may be that having run the solution(s) again and again that file is now corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Here solution with using hold space ( ... probably not what you looking for):

```
sed -n '
/\#\# START UPSTREAM/!{H;}; 
/\#\# START UPSTREAM/{p;}; 
${x;p;}' /etc/nginx/upstream.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Perl rather than `sed` for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $config   = '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf';
my $upstream = '/etc/nginx/upstream.conf';

local $/;
open FILE, "<$config" or die $!;   my $cnf=<FILE>; close FILE;
open FILE, "<$upstream" or die $!; my $inc=<FILE>; close FILE;

$cnf =~ s/(## START UPSTREAM)[\s\S]*?(## END UPSTREAM)/$1\n$inc$2/;

open FILE, ">$config" or die $!; print FILE $cnf; close FILE;
```